# openssl_encrypt aes-256-cbc not working for more than 4 parameters json

Tags: php

```
case 1 -> $data = '{"EmployeeCode":"demo2","PartnerCode":"abcd","FlexUser":"false","Role":"INV"}'<br/>
case 2 -> $data = 
'{"EmployeeCode":"demo2","PartnerCode":"abcd","FlexUser":"false","Role":"INV","CheckupEligibility" : 
  "true"}';
$method = "aes-256-cbc"; 
$first_key = "A1HS8CUR1TY@9812";
$iv = "A1HS8CUR1TY@9812";
$secret = "A1HREW30SEC@1720";
$first_encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data,$method,$first_key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$iv);
```

I'm trying to encrypt the above json string using aes-256-cbc but not getting any output in case2, whereas getting a proper output in case 1.Could you please help me out.